# Determine if system wide backup is enabled programmatically

Tags: android, backup, android-backup-service

I was wondering if it possible to determine if the user has enabled the option to backup application data to the cloud from within my android app.

I can determine this from the command line, from adb shell by calling:

```
bmgr enabled
```

Does android provide an API to do so from code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/bmgr.html there is no API to do what you ask - only interfaces an app can implement to interact with the BackupManager regarding its data backup/restore..

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    int backups_enabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), "backup_enabled");
    Log.i("TAG", "Backups are "+(backups_enabled == 1 ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
} catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Setting not found", e);
}
```

Note: In order for backups to work, the device also needs to be provisioned (Settings.Global.DEVICE_PROVISIONED).

Comment: This comes from the `Settings.BACKUP_ENABLED` constant, which is marked as `@UnsupportedAppUsage` as of Version R, so won't work on newer phones